# JSON sending fine as key:answer, not key:array

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I'm having an issue where my android application is getting a positive result from our key:answer POST, but not from key:array for the same structure. My web developer is saying that I'm not serialising it properly, but every JSON tester I can find on the web is quite happy with the send, just not our web server. I'm sending my JSON in groups of 10 as a string (We had a previous issue where when sending about 200 keys it was giving issues, so I've split it down to 10 per send) and the JSON sent is as follows:

```
[{
    "jobDetails": {
        "jobid": "7",
        "company": {
            "cmid": "30"
        }
    },
    "formName": "IPE Report",
    "formHeader": "Activity",
    "key": "date_inspDate",
    "answervalues": "18-07-2017"
}, {
    "jobDetails": {
        "jobid": "7",
        "company": {
            "cmid": "30"
        }
    },
    "formName": "IPE Report",
    "formHeader": "Activity",
    "key": "text_clientRep",
    "answervalues": "testrep"
}, {
    "jobDetails": {
        "jobid": "7",
        "company": {
            "cmid": "30"
        }
    },
    "formName": "IPE Report",
    "formHeader": "Activity",
    "key": "text_designCode",
    "answervalues": "destdesign"
}, {
    "jobDetails": {
        "jobid": "7",
        "company": {
            "cmid": "30"
        }
    },
    "formName": "IPE Report",
    "formHeader": "Activity",
    "key": "text_qcPlan",
    "answervalues": "testqc"
}, {
    "jobDetails": {
        "jobid": "7",
        "company": {
            "cmid": "30"
        }
    },
    "formName": "IPE Report",
    "formHeader": "Activity",
    "key": "text_equipDesc",
    "answervalues": "testdesc"
}, {
    "jobDetails": {
        "jobid": "7",
        "company": {
            "cmid": "30"
        }
    },
    "formName": "IPE Report",
    "formHeader": "Activity",
    "key": "text_companyName",
    "answervalues": "testco"
}, {
    "jobDetails": {
        "jobid": "7",
        "company": {
            "cmid": "30"
        }
    },
    "formName": "IPE Report",
    "formHeader": "Activity",
    "key": "text_drawingNo",
    "answervalues": "testrev"
}, {
    "jobDetails": {
        "jobid": "7",
        "company": {
            "cmid": "30"
        }
    },
    "formName": "IPE Report",
    "formHeader": "Activity",
    "key": "Detail",
    "answervalues": [{
        "register": 1,
        "values": "act2"
    }, {
        "register": 2,
        "values": "act3"
    }]
}, {
    "jobDetails": {
        "jobid": "7",
        "company": {
            "cmid": "30"
        }
    },
    "formName": "IPE Report",
    "formHeader": "Activity",
    "key": "Regulated",
    "answervalues": [{
        "register": 1,
        "values": "YES"
    }, {
        "register": 2,
        "values": "NO"
    }]
}, {
    "jobDetails": {
        "jobid": "7",
        "company": {
            "cmid": "30"
        }
    },
    "formName": "IPE Report",
    "formHeader": "Activity",
    "key": "Comments",
    "answervalues": [{
        "register": 1,
        "values": "DIMENSIONS CHECK"
    }, {
        "register": 2,
        "values": "HOLD POINT"
    }]
}]
```

All is fine until it hits the Detail key, which is an array. This structure was sending fine last week, they claim they've changed nothing. Is it really a serialisation issue on my side or is the server just not accepting that key as either value or array?

Comment: I can parse it just fine - get a new developer :P

Comment: you are sending an array of objects. Perhaps they are expecting array of strings? Or, perhaps a problem with Content-type or Content-length in your post?

Comment: also, notice the first place you use a number instead of a string is the value for "register" under the Detail key. Could be server expects "1" instead of 1

Comment: "All is fine until it hits the Detail key", what are you referring to here ?    "...a positive result from our key:answer POST, but not from key:array for the same structure....", is your receiver programmed to accept either types of data (string and array)? What error message do you receive?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey They are expecting the 1 instead of "1"

Comment: @blokeish I'm getting" "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message": "JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token;"

Comment: Ha! so they are only accepting String for answervalues. You have valid JSON, whether it is valid for the class it is translating to is another story. Only the service dev can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

From your error message:

*"JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token;"*

I think you problem is in 'answervalues'.

```
/* in some entries you have it as an array of objects*/
"answervalues": [{
        "register": 1,
        "values": "YES"
    }, {
        "register": 2,
        "values": "NO"
    }]

/* while in other entries as a string */
"answervalues": "testrev"
```

Talk with your developer to see how this need to be formatted. I believe the string values also need to be passed as an object in a single array. Something like..

```
"answervalues":  [{
            "register": 1,
            "values":"testrev"
            }]
```